# showDialog button doesent calls method i told him to

Tags: android, dialog

ok I got activity that doesent have his layout, it is only there to take gps coordinates and if he succeed then default camera intent is started, if not i show him dialog where user have 2 buttons one to cancel and go back to starting activity and second one is to try getting picture again (calling method for obtaining gps and then sending to camera intent).

The problem is that sometimes when i hit try again button it doesent call getPicture() methond but just continue on like button was never hit nor the dialog was shown and that problem happens often

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getPicture();
}

public void getPicture(){



    LocationManager locationManager = null;

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        if(MyLocationListener.latitude>0){
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


        } else {

            showDialog(GPS_CANT_CONNECT);
        }
    }else{

        showDialog(GPS_OFF);
    }
}

@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog d = null;
        switch (id){

        case GPS_OFF: {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Please turn on your GPS before taking picture");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Try Again", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getPicture();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartCameraActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            d = builder.create();
            break;
        }
        case GPS_CANT_CONNECT: {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("GPS cant get coordinates! Please make sure that you are outside");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Try Again", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getPicture();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartCameraActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            d = builder.create();
            break;
        }

          return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
d.show();
```

after every `d = builder.create();` line.

because you have only create dialog not show thats why its not showing.

like:

```
case GPS_CANT_CONNECT: {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("GPS cant get coordinates! Please make sure that you are outside");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Try Again", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getPicture();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartCameraActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            d = builder.create();
            d.show();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: that didnt rly help. I still got problem. But when i puted d.show() before return, it started working normaly, but ill have to test it for some more time before i am sure that problem is solved.

Comment: problem still there... i turned gps off, so it should be showing dialog every time i hit "try again" button, but it only show it once, and when i hit it it just disapear like i told him nothing to do in onClick method...

Comment: in your dialog if i press try again then is call getPicture() then if i not get latitude then again dilog open. this prossess is continue till i press cancle button. then what is issue. can you explain me in detail??

Comment: Yes that should be happening. Dialog should be opening continuously until i press cancel, but it is not doing that. It shows dialog maybe once or two times max, and after that it just close dialog and i have empty activity. 

It is like he isnt calling showDialog() if he dont get latitude or he is not calling getPicture() in button.onClick()